# How to use three nested for-loops in java for an inverted pyramid with _?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to create a pyramid with three nested for loops using a scanner.

I have to achieve this

```
Enter a number
6
1 2 3 4 5 6 

- 1 2 3 4 5 

- - 1 2 3 4

- - - 1 2 3

- - - - 1 2

- - - - - 1
```

I basically have tried this, I know it is wrong, but I know what I have to do and I'm not sure how to write it.

```
Scanner ent= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int x= ent.nextInt();


for(int a = x; a >= 1; a--) {
    for(int c=1;c<=x;c++) {
        System.out.print("_");
        for(int b = 1; b <= a; b++) { 
            System.out.print(d + " "); 
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide this pattern into two.

1. dash
2. Numbers from 1 to n

First calculate how many times you need to print this pattern. Here 6 times.

```
    int n=in.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {

    }
```

For each time you need to print dashes followed by numbers.

1. Dash

   ```
   ------------
   Row | Dashes
   ------------
    1  |  0
    2  |  1
    3  |  2
    4  |  3
    5  |  4
    6  |  5
   ```

So am introducing a variable dashes=0 and increment the dashes for each row.

```
    int n=in.nextInt();     
    int dashes=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=dashes;j++)
            System.out.print("-");
        dashes++;
    }
```

2. Numbers start from 1 and ends with (n-i+1)

   ```
   ------------
   Row | Numbers (n-i+1)
   ------------
    1  |  123456 
    2  |  12345
    3  |  1234
    4  |  123
    5  |  12
    6  |  1
   ```

So the final code is

```
    int n=in.nextInt();

    int dashes=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=dashes;j++)
            System.out.print("-");

        for(int k=1;k<=n-i+1;k++)
            System.out.print(k);

        // for next row - starts in new line
        System.out.println();
        dashes++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int x = ent.nextInt();

for (int i=0; i < x; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < i; ++j) System.out.print("- ");
    for (int j=1; j <= (x-i); ++j) {
        if (j > 1) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

1 2 3 4 5 6
- 1 2 3 4 5
- - 1 2 3 4
- - - 1 2 3
- - - - 1 2
- - - - - 1
```

The logic is to use two separate inner loops, one for the dashes, which come first, and another for the numbers.  The loop for dashes runs from 0 to `i-1`, i.e. one position before the outer loop.  Then, for the rest of the line, we print numbers, from 1 to `x - i`.